# Is there any way that I, a CLI PHP developer, could "hook into" some kind of AI blackbox?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

For many years now, I have heard about "AI" and "neural networks" and all these buzzwords, and it is regularly claimed on Slashdot that this or that open source program is able to "do AI". But then I go to its website and I have no idea what I'm even looking at, let alone how to actually use it. I give up and forget about it... until the next time I hear something about "AI" and how it's now apparently seen as something as fundamental and crucial as a variable or function or constant.

Is this just utter fiction, made up nonsense, vaporware, or is it concretely possible to "hook into AI" like a "turn-key blackbox"?

I imagine that, from CLI PHP, I send a command such as:

```
ai_blackbox.exe --input="What are 1 + 1?"
```

And the `ai-blackbox.exe` then calculates my input, by spinning up a whole "neutral net" or whatever AI does internally, and quickly spits out:

```
2
```

Is that "a thing"? Is there something fundamentally wrong with my understanding of this?

Of course, in reality, I assume that the input is much more advanced than that. Something which would be unbearably slow to calculate in PHP but goes super fast with the `ai-blackbox.exe`?

Every single time I have asked anyone about this, I have never got a clear answer or reply. They either agree with me that it's just nonsense and doesn't actually exist, or they link me to some massive manual which I'm utterly unable to comprehend.

Can I actually use this, today, for anything meaningful, in a simple way?

Or is this exclusively useful for a handful of scientists doing some very specific work and who need to "train" the AI in all kinds of ways before it can answer anything?

Comment: The question sounds over-broad to me.  It also seems poorly researched: you can easily find many existing uses of AI in standard resources, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence#Applications, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning#Applications.  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking, and to show us what you've found in your research so far.  If your question is already answered in standard places like Wikipedia, you probably haven't done enough research of your own before asking.

Comment: Finally, if you'd like to make the best use of this site, I encourage you to tone down the emotion words (extreme words like "nonsense", "vaporware", black-and-white thinking that this is either amazing or nonsense, etc.) and try to identify a factual question that can be objectively answered.  We're not looking for rants or "this seems outrageous; am I right?" or calls to discussion.  Perhaps "What are the limits of modern AI" or "Does AI have any applications?" would be a better question from that perspective (though it still has the other issues).

Answer (score 2):

> something which would be unbearably slow to calculate in PHP but goes super fast with the ai-blackbox.exe

I think you are massively overestimating the state-of-the-art of AI.

1. Any AI blackbox is implemented in *some* programming language. PHP is not the fastest language, but its slowness is likely to be a constant factor in any computation. So the difference between you calculating it in PHP and the black-box calculating it is mostly whether you wrote the code yourself or someone else wrote it.
2. A general purpose question-and-answer system is actually likely to be *slower* than something you write yourself, because you probably have some idea of the kinds of questions you are going to be feeding the system, and could optimize based on this.
3. You seem to want to phrase your questions using natural language i.e. English or another human language. [Natural Language Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) is a *huge* open area of research, and is far from solved. There are some existing techniques for this, but they are far from perfect. Anyone who has spent a day with a Siri, Google Home or Amazon Echo sees that we are a long way from being able to properly process human language.
4. What kinds of questions do you want to answer? Even assuming you could fully process the input to your question, you're going to have a hard time if the range of possible solutions includes "all of human knowledge." Representing such knowledge, collecting the information, and searching it, are all areas of current research.

   Most modern AI techniques are for specialized AI i.e. you train a Neural Network to perform *a single task* very well. So they don't really apply to what you're talking about.

> They either agree with me that it's just nonsense and doesn't actually exist, or they link me to some massive manual which I'm utterly unable to comprehend.

This is because AI is *hard*. Even with specialized AI, it takes a lot of expert knowledge to train a neural network. Generalized AI is even harder.

> Can I actually use this, today, for anything meaningful, in a simple way?

I think the closest you will get to this is the [Wolfram Alpha API](https://products.wolframalpha.com/api/). This is a system that lets you put in a question, and *sometimes* returns an answer. It's best with math-style things, or with facts it can guess from i.e. Wikipedia. It is far from perfect, and far from the kind of generalized AI you're talking about. It's also proprietary software i.e. you can only run it on their servers and make requests to them. And it is not free after a certain number of requests.

You can test it out at https://www.wolframalpha.com/.

> Or is this exclusively useful for a handful of scientists doing some very specific work and who need to "train" the AI in all kinds of ways before it can answer anything?

There is a reason there is currently a huge demand for data science and AI specialists. Currently, it takes a lot of specific work to train an AI even to perform a single task. A Neural Network is basically a graph with weighted edges, and you can automatically optimize the edge weights, but you have to figure out the graph structure yourself. There is some work into "Automated Machine Learning", which tries to guess these structures automatically, but it's very much an open problem.

Essentially, it currently takes an expert to train an algorithm to perform *a single task*. General question and answering is mostly out of reach, even for experts.